# Xcode TableView Issue

Tags: xcode, ios5, uitableview

Right now I am putting a tableview in my app. when I drag a `UITableView` on the screen and position it, Xcode does not display the content type setting, which I need to change for this tableview. This tableview is in an xib file, separate from the main storyboard file. How would I change that setting?

Thanks,
Virindh Borra

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "content type setting"?

Comment: Where you can set weather it is a dynamic prototype or static content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change/check the content type settings yourself by looking in the attributes inspector  on the utilities.

Comment: my problem is that, that pane isnt there in the attributes inspector.